# Pandas index column

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to concat three files into one xlsx file. I'm able to concat but the index column is not getting removed. My Dataframe after using concat function is having index column of all three xlsx file from 0 to 3000 for three times. How should I approach to resolve the issue?

Details -

I have amex-listing.xlsx file with 3 worksheet.

sheet1 = nyse

sheet2 = amex

sheet3 = nasdaq

**Code** -

```
xls = pd.ExcelFile('amex-listing.xlsx')
exchanges = xls.sheet_names
pd.set_option("display.max_columns",100)
final_file = 'listing.xlsx'
listings = []
for exchange in exchanges:
    listing = pd.read_excel('amex-listing.xlsx',sheet_name=exchange, na_values='NaN', index_col=False)
    listing['exchange'] = exchange
    sup_df = pd.DataFrame()
    sup_df = listing.append(sup_df)
    listings.append(sup_df)

listings = pd.concat(listings)
```

**Output dataframe-**

[index_issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1GjYA.jpg)

[dataframe_view_after_concat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7VG34.png)

How can I remove/ignore/drop unnamed index column? Any solution possible?

**Output xlxs file having unnamed index column -**

[amex-index](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tZAqw.png)

[amex-nasdaq_index](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uaVkM.png)

[nasdaq-nyse_index](https://i.stack.imgur.com/07Vpl.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is Pandas' convention to show row index on the left.  You can't remove the index  (unless you set other kind of index, but still index there).  If you don't want to see the repeating indices (0 to 3000 repeating 3 times), you can reset the index to re-serialize the index numbers (0 to around 9002) by [`reset_index()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html), as follows:

Assuming the name of your dataframe after concat is `df`

```
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
```

### Edit

If you just don't want to see the row index and is fine to set your column `Symbol` as the index, you can use:

```
df = df.set_index('Symbol')
```

Then, you will no longer see the original default range index. Note that in this way, rows of the same `Symbol` will be placed together.  You have to consider whether this is fine for you.

Comment: I tried but it's not working. 

Error - 


AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'reset_index'


I just want to remove that column. What is the best approach/solution for this?

Comment: @starlord  This should be done after your code `listings = pd.concat(listings)`   At that time, `listings` should already be a dataframe returned from `pd.concat()`.  Try again.

Comment: @starlord  See my edit above for any possible solution.  But note that rows of the  same `Symbol` will be placed together.

Comment: Thanks, it worked! Also, how can I remove that unnamed column from the Dataframe before dumping data into the excel file.

Comment: Sure :)
Also, how to remove that unnamed column from the Dataframe in order to have a clean data file.

Comment: @starlord  You can remove a column by e.g. `df = df.drop('Unnamed 1', axis=1)`  Plug in the column names in the first parameter of `.drop`.